# Serialization to collection of objects in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I have function for serialization to jsonObject in swift:

```
func JSONWork() -> Any {

            let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json")!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOf: url)!
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: [])

            return json
        }
```

Is any method for serialization into collection of objects (something like `JSONSerialization.jsonObjectCollection`)?

Comment: You don't want to use third-party frameworks, right?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov if is it possible? And if it's not, may be your recommend any framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use on of frameworks for JSON mapping. Read about pros and cons of popular solutions [here](https://github.com/bwhiteley/JSONShootout) and choose best for you. Also, you can read [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) article from Swift blog, it's a recommendation by Apple to use only standard API classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: file)
        {
            let jsonObj = JSON(data: data)
            let array = jsonObj.arrayValue
        }
```

[Use Swifty JSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)